# Empty set isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Two sets are isomorphic if there is a bijection between them. But there is no bijection between two empty sets.

> Are two empty sets "indistinguishable"?

If so, what formal meaning this "indistinguishable" has?

It may be a silly question, however I cannot find any answer on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is** a bijection between two empty sets: the empty function!

A function from $A$ to $B$ is a set $X$ such that

- Every element of $X$ is an ordered pair $(a, b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, and
- For each $a\in A$, there is *exactly one* $b\in B$ such that $(a, b)\in X$.

Well, this means that the empty set $\emptyset$ is itself a function from the emptyset to the emptyset, and it's clearly a bijection.

---

Indeed, any two empty sets are not just isomorphic - they're *equal*. If you're a category theorist, equality of sets is an [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) notion, but it's fundamental to set theory. The relevant axiom is [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). There are times when we drop the axiom of extensionality - e.g. any set theory with [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory) - but those are exceptions.

Comment: you mean that $\emptyset \times \emptyset$ is a valid graph?

Comment: @SMaks Yes, and in fact $\emptyset\times\emptyset=\emptyset$. $\emptyset$ is a bijection from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.

Comment: So the axiom of extensionality allows to say, that $\emptyset\times\emptyset=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: @SMaks Not in one step. First, you show that $\emptyset\times \emptyset$ has no elements (this isn't hard: any element of $\emptyset\times\emptyset$ has to be an ordered pair, and then its first (or second) coordinate is an element of $\emptyset$); *then* Extensionality implies $\emptyset\times \emptyset=\emptyset$.

Comment: @SMaks Not only $\emptyset\times\emptyset$ but $\emptyset\times A=\emptyset.$

Comment: And, indeed, $\emptyset$ is an injection from $\emptyset$ to $A$, for every $A$! (Note that by contrast if $A$ is *nonempty*, then there are no functions from $A$ to $\emptyset$ at all - this is a good point to be clear on.)